# Python urllib2 web scraping 401 error but reachable in browser

Tags: python, urllib2

I am trying to scrape this and similar pages using Python:

```
url = "http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v521/n7553/full/nature14410.html"
```

While I can navigate to this page with my browser, I'm getting a 401 authentication error with urllib2 and can't figure out why. **To be clear, I understand that the article is behind a paywall but I'm only interested in things like the title, authors, volume, references, etc, which are freely available and I obviously don't have subscription.**

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
urlopen("http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v521/n7553/full/nature14410.html")
```

I've tried changing the user-agent thinking that the site somehow is detecting that I'm not using a browser

```
request = urllib2.Request(url)
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.add_headers = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
```

As a non-web developer, it's not clear how I can solve this or figure out where the obstacle.

Answer (score 1):

If I use Developer tools in Chrome it shows that even in the browser that particular page is giving a `401 Unauthorized` response. Unfortunately, `urllib2` always raises an exception on an error response, and makes it harder to see the contents.

Complicating this case even further is the fact that `nature.com` doesn't seem to be setting the `Content-Encoding` header to indicate that it has gzipped the response, even though it has.

Try something like this:

```
import urllib2
import cStringIO as StringIO
import gzip

def getDataFromCompressedError(url):
    try:
        urllib2.urlopen(url)
    except urllib2.URLError as e:
        data = e.read()
        strfile = StringIO.StringIO(data)
        gz = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=strfile)
        return gz.read()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print getDataFromCompressedError("http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v521/n7553/full/nature14410.html")
```